# Sharepoint Managed MetaData Service Migration 2010 - 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, migration, mms

I have successfully migrated MMS from SP 2010 to SP 2013
Is there any limitations while this is done ??
Any data / feature lose ?

Comment: Hi Danny Could you share the details of how you've done the migration?